# Check if update executed in pecee-pixie

Tags: php, mysql

I am using [pecee-pixie](https://github.com/skipperbent/pecee-pixie#query-events)

I run:

```
$result = $query_builder->where("id", "=", 4)->update($data_array);
```

and it executes correctly. However I want to check if the query got executed and if it failed I would like to insert the data to the array. Alas the where statements are not primary keys so i cannot use ON DUPLICATE KEY statement.

How can i check if the last query was executed with a success?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used the method before but this library has updateOrInsert method that might work. 
You can also easily check if the query was executed by checking the affected row count

```
$result = $query_builder->where("id", "=", 4)->update($data_array);
$count = $result->rowCount();
if($count > 0) {
//update executed
} else {
//update failed do the insert
}
```